# How to show a FileContentResult containing pdf data into browser

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a byte array containing data of a pdf file which I have read from remote:

```
byte[] filedata = webClient.DownloadData(fPath);
```

I am sending the filedata from controller to view in an ajax call:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content - Disposition", "inline; filename = test.pdf");
return File(files[0], "application/pdf");
```

I want to show that pdf file on the browser, I have created an  element in my html but I don't know how to show the file. 
Could somebody please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: You will need to open the URL corresponding to that controller action.

Comment: won't the page reload in that case? I want to maintain the same web page and update just the embed section with the pdf file. Is that possible?

Comment: You could look at a 3rd party js library maybe. I don't think you can do it just in mvc

Comment: Do you want to show the pdf in a new window, or the same one in some form of control?

Comment: @R2D2 I want to show it in an embed element which is a html element that allows to show pdf files. And on the same page not another window.

Answer (score 0):

I have a system that displays PDFs. I utilise a view that contains an IFrame. So suppose you have a button that says "View File", I have this open up the view that contains the IFrame. The source of the frame points to the controller action that returns your File result.

```
<iframe id="iframepdf" src="@Url.Action("ReturnMyFile", "MyController",
new { filePath = pathToFile})"></iframe>
```

You can pass the path as a variable to get the file bytes from where they are kept.
This then renders the Pdf within the IFrame

Hope that helps